# Verbose output from Jenkins CI with Subversion

Tags: svn, jenkins

I have a pretty basic subversion workflow.  I commit to an external subversion repository, Jenkins Subversion plugin polls for changes, the change triggers a new build, and then that build gets sent via SSH (or SFTP) to my remote site.

The problem is that this is all I get when I look to the console output in Jenkins for what's going on:

```
Started by an SCM change
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Auto Deployment Test\workspace
Updating svn/{project Name}/Branches/2014june17/ at revision '2014-08-15T11:26:08.150 -0500'
U         updated_url.php
At revision 9886

SSH: Connecting from host [laptop-pc]
SSH: Connecting with configuration [Dev Server] ...
SSH: Disconnecting configuration [Dev Server] ...
SSH: Transferred 8926 file(s)
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Well that's groovy and all that it says that, but I'd really like to have more verbose output as to what files were put where, if the configuration worked, and (dread) if using a Windows machine to a Unix deployment environment caused any strange file path configurations.

Edit: ** 8/20/2014 **

To answer the question of the build environment, it's a SCM change with Subversion.  It's a simple manual poll.  When the build gets triggered, the changes are pulled, the post-build action is to use SSH over FTP.  That sends the SFTP over.

I have verified that everything works perfectly.  However, I'm going to want to iterate and build on this very simple process.  But it looks like it'd be difficult if I can't get a more verbose output of what's going on under the hood.  So I want to know if there's a way to tell Jenkins to be more verbose, of if Jenkins leaves verbosity up to the plugin, etc.

Edit:  ** 8/21/2014 **

Thanks to David W., the option is a bit hidden, or at least poorly named to me.  Under the /configure, you have to click on the dropdown "Publisher defaults", configure defaults, and select the verbose checkbox from the list.

Comment: What's your build step (Ant? Maven? Batch? Bash?)? What's your configuration? By the looks of it, you only configured an SCM checkout (SVN) and some post-build actions (SSH).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is the ssh being handled? Is it with the SSH plugin, you doing the commands from the command line, or are you using Ant or Apache to do the SSH?

The Jenkins FTP Publish and SSH Public plugins both have a "verbose" checkbox in their configuration.